# passing an array reference to a function in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, reference

how to pass reference to an array to function in scala.

for example following is a function in c/c++

how to write code for array ref in scala ?

```
int RMQUtil(int *st, int ss, int se, int qs, int qe, int index)
{
// If segment of this node is a part of given range, then return the
// min of the segment
if (qs <= ss && qe >= se)
    return st[index];

// If segment of this node is outside the given range
if (se < qs || ss > qe)
    return INT_MAX;

// If a part of this segment overlaps with the given range
int mid = getMid(ss, se);
return minVal(RMQUtil(st, ss, mid, qs, qe, 2*index+1),
              RMQUtil(st, mid+1, se, qs, qe, 2*index+2));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def RMQUtil(st: Array[Int], ss: Int, se: Int, qs: Int, qe: Int, index: Int): Int = {
  if (qs <= ss && qe >= se)
    return st(index)
  if (se < qs || ss > qe)
    return Int.MaxValue

  val mid = getMid(ss, se) // I assume this is something like (ss + se) / 2
  Math.min(RMQUtil(st, ss, mid, qs, qe, 2*index+1), RMQUtil(st, mid+1, se, qs, qe, 2*index+2))
}
```

Comment: @user2124441 a little comment about your suggested edit - it is not necessary to include the `return` keyword for the last statement

Answer (score 3):

For the multiple arguments of the method consider

```
case class Params(ss: Int, se: Int, qs: Int, qe: Int, index: Int)
```

The Scala re-coding for the asked method above,

```
def RMQUtil(st: Array[Int], p: Params): Int = {
  if (p.qs <= p.ss && p.qe >= p.se) 
    st(index)
  else if (p.se < p.qs || p.ss > p.qe)
    Int.MaxValue
  else {
    val mid: Int = getMid(ss, se)
    Math.min( RMQUtil(st, Params(p.ss, mid, p.qs, p.qe, 2*index+1)),
              RMQUtil(st, Params(mid+1, p.se, p.qs, p.qe, 2*index+2)))
  }
}
```

Comment: `Params(p.ss, mid, p.qs, p.qe, 2*index+1)` could be `p.copy(se = mid, index = 2 * index + 1)`. This way it easier to grasp what is changed and what is not. Not much win in having parameters passed this way (wrapped in a case class).

Comment: @om-nom-nom Thanks for the good observation, indeed not much gain other than utilising the copying method...